# Why is my transaction not included into blocks with smaller gas prices in them?

Tags: mining, gas-price, blocks, pending-transactions

I created a transaction with gas price 1.1 GWEI. It has been pending for 3 hours, and yet - during just the last 75 blocks - several 1 GWEI transactions have been included.

In other words, gas price is clearly not the only determinant of which transactions are picked to be included in a block.

It seems to me that (at least some of) the Ethereum miners might prioritize older transactions over transactions with higher gas prices.

#### Box Plots of Gas Price in GWEI for the last 75 blocks:

[image: Box Plots of Gas Price in GWEI for the last 75 blocks]

Notice that in the Box Plots, there seems to be two types of blocks. Those that include 1 GWEI transactions, and those that don't.

My hypothesis is that there are two main types of miners:

1. Those that mine the transactions that pay the highest gas prices
2. Those that mine the transactions (minimum 1 GWEI) that have been waiting the longest.

Considering how common "1 GWEI-blocks" seem to be - who are these miners? And why are they picking old pending transactions, rather than those that pay the most?

Disclaimer: I don't actually know that it is the oldest transactions that are included in the "1 GWEI-blocks", I'm just assuming this, since they are clearly not picking the highest gas price transactions. Another explanation would be that these miners pick transactions randomly.

Comment: Can you tell us your transaction ID?

Comment: @EdmundEdgar https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb21994057d639b60d746a3a035afe933b3bf2ba7e5bcdeb96fd41578e4695250